# Mapping of an object that contains two persistent objects

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I am trying to map a class (object that is not related to database) that contains two persistent object, is there a way to do this? If there is a keyword/attribute to be used just mention it and I can start from there. If there is no direct way could you please briefly explain on high level the alternative steps?

Classes

```
class NotPersistent {
    Private Persistent1 persistent1;
    Private Persistent2 persistent2;
    ...
}

class Persistent1 {
    Private Integer id;
    Private String column1;
    ...
}

class Persistent2 {
    Private Integer id;
    Private String column1;
    ...
}
```

Hibernate mapping that I have done so far

```
<class name="NotPersistent">
    <one-to-one class="Persistent1"></one-to-one>
    <one-to-one class="Persistent2"></one-to-one>
    ...
</class>

<class name="Persistent1">
    <one-to-one class="NotPersistent"></one-to-one>
    <id ...>
    <property ...>
    ...
</class>

<class name="Persistent2">
    <one-to-one class="NotPersistent"></one-to-one>
    <id ...>
    <property ...>
    ...
</class>
```

If im on the right track, what should be in the attribute of `<class name="NotPersistent" ..`

Comment: Just to get it right. (And no offense meant) If the NotPersistent Class is not represented in the DB why are you trying to map it in Hibernate, which sole purpose is to persist stuff into the DB? If you could explain on the underlying problem a bit this might help to advise on a solution.

Comment: I don't have control over the class and the underlying CRUD operations, they call something like `hibernateTemplate.save(NotPersistent.class, obj)` and ask me to map this to existing database tables. Is this something impossible to accomplish?

Comment: Ok, you should probably edit the "(object that is not related to database)" part out of the question, since it is confusing. And you are in fact trying to save the object in the DB. You are just looking for the right mapping. The Question left is what can you do for a mapping? Can you map in away that would need a JoinTable, what other restrictions are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, without anything else the approach taken so far looks right. You map using the `one-to-one` tag.

```
<class name="NotPersistent" table="xxx">
     <one-to-one name="persistent1" class="Persistent1" cascade="save-update"></one-to-one>

<class name="NotPersistent" table="xxx">
     <one-to-one name="nonPersistent" class="NonPersistent"></one-to-one>
```

Since I did not use XML mapping extensivly I don't know the  exact syntax. But the approach should get you started. Another question is are the Entities realy One to One? It does not look likely, because then the two persistent entities are so closely related that they could just be coupled directly using a Foreignkey and just one Entity.